# replace & for &amp;

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to validate using W3C validation system and i get an error:

> Line 59, Column 47: character "&" is the first character of a delimiter but occurred as data

I know the reason why:

> You used an unescaped ampersand "&": this may be valid in some contexts, but it is recommended to use "&amp", which is always safe.

In the form, i've entered it like this

> SONY & BMG MUSIC ENTERTAINMENT

If i go in phpadmin, in the table, i can see the data correctly

> SONY & BMG MUSIC ENTERTAINMENT

Does it mean that i have to enter it using "&amp"  ... this is crazy, what if i have a text... do i have to replace every & for "&amp"

I'm sure there's is a better way to do this.. any hints or ideas?

Thanks

Comment: How are you using that data? what is on line 59?

Answer (score 3):

You should only escape your data for HTML when you use it in the context of HTML.

Use [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when you output your data.  For example:

```
$title="SONY & BMG MUSIC ENTERTAINMENT";
echo htmlspecialchars($title);
```

It is best practice to leave the data plain in the database, as you may want to use it in a completely different context for something else in the future.  That is, don't escape your data prior to inserting into the database.  Only worry about it when you output it.