# Automatically replace "&" with "&amp;"

Tags: php, wordpress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [replace & for &amp;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6616797/replace-for-amp)

For a wordpress page to be validated, all `&` should be replaced with `&amp;`
I know java but i do not know PHP. So how do i do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) before printing:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape ampersands `&` as well as quotes and brackets using the [`htmlspecialchars()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said, `htmlspecialchars()` works. Also check out `htmlentities()` which has a broader range of characters to replace for further scrubbing of the string.